# Cannot import python file inside another python file in the same subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I have a file called `blog/urls.py` inside which I am importing a function from `blog/views.py` called allblogs
Even if I write `import .views` or `import views` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views' even though both files are in the same folder. How do I resolve this ?`

Answer (score 0):

the search path must be located in `sys.path`.
see https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

to list your current directory, use `os.curdir`; you can then compare to see if it is in the system path

```
import os
os.curdir
import sys
for p in sys.path: 
   print(p);
```

Comment: What if the folder path is in sys.path but I cannot import the file

Comment: The name of the folder I am working in is in sys.path and I am able to import other files from that folder I just cannot import that file for some reason

Comment: This is true for other projects I am working on too

Answer (score 0):

In django,you need to add this to your `setting.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then you could use `import view.xxxx`

This will make you more convenient every time you want to import the module.